# Magnetic Permeability & Reluctance on old exam question

Tags: electromagnetism, homework-and-exercises

This is a past exam question from one of our lectures, and we have an issue with (i), I believe I need to use the equation $\rho=\frac{RA}{l}$, but I am not sure - could someone enlighten me on the issue?

> A mild steel ring of magnetic permeability 380, having a cross sectional area of $500mm^2$ and a mean circumference of $400mm$, has a coil of $200$ turns wound uniformly around it.
>
> Given that the magnetic permeability of free space is $400 nH/m$ determine:
>
> - (i) The reluctance of the ring.
> - (ii) The current required to produce a flux of $800\mu$ Wb in the ring.

Comment: The equation above has nothing to do with the problem below.  In case the problem would be in SI units, I might be able to solve it... :/

Comment: That figure for magnetic permeability of free space doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: I was puzzled by N=200 in the numerator and I found it was NOT necessary.
Please check http://www.codecogs.com/library/physics/magnetism/magnetic-reluctance.php for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As Pygmalion says, that equation is not related to the question. [$\rho=R\frac{A}{l}$ is *electrical* resistivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistivity), not magnetic.

As for part (i), this is simply answered from all the values given just plugged in to the appropriate formula for [*magnetic* reluctance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance):

$$\mathcal{R}=\frac{\mathcal{F}}{\Phi}=\frac{l}{\mu_0\mu_rA}=\frac{(200\cdot400mm)}{(4\pi\times10^{-7}Hm^{-1})(380)(500mm^2)}=\text{answer}$$